# The assigned bam file is not recognised

Tags: bash

I am currently aligning paired-end reads to the reference genome (genome index created) and the goal is to end up with a single bam file. This is the code that I am using and everything works fine until the last code line. I get the error message that the file 'SRR5882797_10M.bam' doesn't exist. This file doesn't exist yet, of course, but this is what I am trying to send my output file to and is therefore, supposed to be created with this code. I am not sure how to fix this since it seems to be asking me to have a file in the folder already. Thanks :)

bwa mem -t 2 Refs/Athaliana/Arabidopsis_thaliana_TAIR10 02_trimmedData/fastq/SRR5882797_10M_1.fastq.gz 02_trimmedData/fastq/SRR5882797_10M_2.fastq.gz |
samtools view -bhS -F4 - > 03_alignedData/bam/SRR5882797_10M.bam

Comment: The directory does exist. It just doesn't recognise the file which cannot be made before the analysis is done.

Comment: That error (`No such file or directory`) also happens when any part of the path is wrong. For Example:  `mkdir S ; cd S ; echo "test" >2/3/both2-and-3-dont-exist.txt`
`2/3/both2-and-3-dont-exist.txt: No such file or directory.`